# Connect to SQL Server 2012 using jTDs

Tags: sql-server, jtds

Trying to connect to SQL Server 2012 (Express Edition) using JDBC.

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class MSSqlTestConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (
                "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;instance=LOCALDB#B431115D;DatabaseName=foo","sa","my_password"
            );
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried every possible combination available. Here is the full stack trace :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'sa'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:632)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at MSSqlTestConnection.main(MSSqlTestConnection.java:10)
```

Pipe and TCP/IP is enabled

Mixed Authentication mode is enabled

Works fine with Management Studio when I login using "sa"

Ive pretty much tried everything. I cant seem to find a solution. I tried changing instance=SQLExpress. Removing instance property. Adding username and password property. Adding databasename property. Nothing works.

Any help would be appreciated.

**SOLUTION :**

I re-installed SQL Server 2012. Finally got to the working connection string. Turns out Microsoft SQL Server 2012 has changed the name of the default instance. It is now MSSQLSERVER instead of SQLExpress. You can choose your own instance i.e default or named while setting up SQL Server 2012.

```
Connection Connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instance=MSSQLSERVER;DatabaseName=Database_name",user,password);
```

Also don't forget to use mixed authentication mode while setting up SQL Server.

Comment: Mixed authentication mode... that had me wondering what was wrong for an hour :( good tip!

Comment: hi may I know what version of jtds you are using?

Comment: and did you get this error message ? ERROR: Exception Caught! - Charset 0x0904000128/Cp850 is not supported by the JVM.

Comment: @AuroraBlaze: I don't remember the version I was using when I posted this. Its been a long time. As for your second error, the exception you are seeing is because the CP850 is a charset that is not (as of yet) supported by JVM. Check (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html). You can use the ISO-8859-1 is you are looking for Latin encoding.

Comment: hi, I had tried several methods like updating the JDK and re-installing the JDK, but none of them work. By the way, May I know if you connect into the database via asyn task or in the main thread?

Comment: I think it was the main thread. I dont think updating the JDK is going to be of any help. Check if charsets.jar. is missing from your JVM installer. If not this, the problem might be because you are using an 'English only' version. You will have to change it to support international languages.

Comment: Yes the charset.jar is in my jre/lib folder. May I know where can I get the International languages type? May I have the link please? because I download the JDK from this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html (Java Platform (JDK) 8u25)  and it dont seem to work

Comment: Surely when you connected from SSMS you noticed there was nothing resembling `LOCALDB#B431115D` in the connection window?

Comment: @user2339071 If you solved your problem, you should post the solution as an answer rather than edit the solution in your question. Then accept the answer. That or accept an answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same symptoms after moving an application from MSSQL Server 2005 to MSSQL Server 2012.

My workaround was to change the connection string from

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://a.example.com/xyz;user=bob;password=xxx
```

to

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://a.example.com/xyz;instance=MSSQLSERVER;user=bob;password=xxx;TDS=7.0
```

For short, I added those two attributes at the end of the string:

```
;instance=MSSQLSERVER;TDS=7.0
```