# Connect MS SQL database from Java in ubuntu environment

Tags: java, sql-server, ubuntu, jtds

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and wanted to connect to the MS SQL server database which is hosted in the same network.
I was able to connect this using Squirrel , yet unable to connect from a java program. These are the tools I and .jars I am using .
Intellij Idea is the tool 
jar are jtds-1.3.1.jar and sqljdbc4.jar
Java version 1.7

I am hoping to develop a web application in the Ubuntu Environment , yet my database will be in Ms Sql windows table. Is this feasible ?
Please intruct me step by step , and sample code to connect ms sql database which s hosted ina wondows environment

Rashen

Comment: Show your code. How did you create the JDBC connection, what error did you get?

Comment: "*I was able to connect this using Squirrel, yet unable to connect from a Java program*" - SQuirrel **is** a Java program. So your problem (which you didn't specify) is in *your* program code, not in the connection itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not change anything that your DB is hosted on Linux / Windows, as long as you can access it through your network.

There is a post where you can see how to connect to your DB from Java using jTDS:
[Connect to SQL Server 2012 using jTDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190583/connect-to-sql-server-2012-using-jtds)

If it does not solve your problem, can you give us your exact error message?

Comment: The *database* is **not** hosted on Linux. The client is.

Comment: As I've just said, it does NOT change anything that your DB is not in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Both microsoft's driver and jTDS works on linux.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx
- http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Their web site have example jdbc urls.

Comment: Did work, actually the user which was created only had the Windows Authentication, yet created a user with SQLAuthentication and this did work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't care about the OS.
Have you tried the recommended way to connect using the MS SQL JDBC Driver?

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

String dbHostName = "windowsHostName";
String dbName = "myDb";
String dbUserName = "myUserName";
String dbPassword = "topSecret";

String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dbHostName + ":1433;" +
   "databaseName=" + dbName + ";user=" + dbUserName + ";password=" + dbPasword + ";";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```